# How do i ensure that the selection of a radio button from a radio group affects the selection of a radio button in a different radio group.

Tags: java, android

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:text="1. Do you have an anti-virus installed on your computer :"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_virus"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="48dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_virusyes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:onClick="assessUserInput"
            android:text="Yes" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_virusno"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="assessUserInput"
            android:text="No" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="48dp"
        android:text="If No, skip question 2"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:text="2. How many anti-viruses do you use on your laptop :"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_avnumber"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="48dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_avnumberone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="assessUserInput"
            android:text="1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_avnumbermore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="assessUserInput"
            android:text="More than 1" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:text="3. Do you use pop-up/advert blockers:"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_adblock"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="48dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_adblockyes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:onClick="assessUserInput"
            android:text="Yes" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_adblockno"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="assessUserInput"
            android:text="No" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

Instead of writing text to guide a user to skip question 2 after he
selects "No" in question 1, i want to be able to find a way to disable   question two using java or xml codes when the user selects a "No". or  automatically take question two away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activity:
(Note:i dont know why you want the strings so i separated them from the disabling method but with this it will disable the radio buttons if the user pressed no and they will enable when the user presses yes)

```
public class main extends Activity
{

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.mainz);
            RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_virus);
            radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    RadioGroup rg1        = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_avnumber);
                    Log.w("","click!");
                    if (checkedId == R.id.radio_virusno) {
                        Log.w("","asdasda");
                        for (int i = 0; i < rg1.getChildCount(); i++) {
                            rg1.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false);
                        }

                    }else
                    {
                        Log.w("","else");
                        for (int i = 0; i < rg1.getChildCount(); i++) {
                            rg1.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(true);
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
        }


        public void assessUserInput(View view){
            //// constructor method for Radio Group : Radio_virus
            RadioGroup rgVirus=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radio_virus);
            String radioVirus=((RadioButton)findViewById(rgVirus.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();

            //// constructor method for Radio Group : Radio_avnumber
            RadioGroup rgAvnNumber=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radio_avnumber);
            String radioAvNumber=((RadioButton)findViewById(rgAvnNumber.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();

            /// constructor method for Radio Group : Radio_adblock
            RadioGroup rgAdBlock=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radio_adblock);
            String radioAdBlock=((RadioButton)findViewById(rgAdBlock.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();

            // constructor method for Input field
            //EditText nameTextField=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
            //String hasName=nameTextField.getText().toString();

        }
    }
```

Used xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:text="1. Do you have an anti-virus installed on your computer :"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_virus"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="48dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_virusyes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Yes" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_virusno"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="No" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="48dp"
        android:text="If No, skip question 2"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:text="2. How many anti-viruses do you use on your laptop :"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_avnumber"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="48dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_avnumberone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_avnumbermore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="More than 1" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:text="3. Do you use pop-up/advert blockers:"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_adblock"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="48dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_adblockyes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Yes" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_adblockno"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="No" />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i appreciate your effort also. But i found it difficult implementing your suggestion directly into my work. I appreciate your response

Comment: I cant still implement your code. what radio group are you referring to from the first line of your code?. Is it the radio group that would disable the buttons in the second radio group? .

Comment: I just posted my activity below for you to help me out...i am lost.

Comment: I need to make the radio button from another group disable another radio group once the button is selected

Comment: what my code does is gets the click in the first radio group question, then it checks if the answer was no, if it is no it will disable all the radio buttons from the second's question radio group

Comment: Ivan, the equals operator if (checkedId = R.id.radio_virusno) between checkedId and R.id.radio_virusno should be "==" i guess. After i used your code, my IDE gives an error on the "checked" in setEnabled(checked). It says it cannot resolve symbol. Or do you think i made an error by putting the code inside a super class such as "public void assessUserInput" as seen below. Please help

Comment: got it to work, ill edit this answer, ill also add the xml since i edited a bit.
also sorry for the delay.

Comment: Thank you very much @ivan. THANK YOUUUUUU!!!!!. I wanted the string because i wanted to use it to display the specific value selected the user using a radio button. I really appreciate your effort. It works!!!

Comment: @jaido no problem c:

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle onClick of your radiobutton :

```
public void assessUserInput(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_virusyes:
                if (checked){
                      for(int i = 0; i <  radio_avnumber.getChildCount(); i++){
               ((RadioButton)radio_avnumber.getChildAt(i)).setEnabled(true);}}
            break;
        case R.id.radio_virusno:
            if (checked){
                for(int i = 0; i <  radio_avnumber.getChildCount(); i++){
        ((RadioButton)radio_avnumber.getChildAt(i)).setEnabled(false);}
    }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i used your code and it did exactly what i wanted. Thanks once again. Sorry for the later reply...

Answer (score 0):

```
public void assessUserInput(View view) {
    //// constructor method for Radio Group : Radio_virus
    RadioGroup rgVirus = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_virus);
    String radioVirus = ((RadioButton) findViewById(rgVirus.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();

    //// constructor method for Radio Group : Radio_avnumber
    RadioGroup rgAvnNumber = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_avnumber);
    String radioAvNumber = ((RadioButton) findViewById(rgAvnNumber.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();

    /// constructor method for Radio Group : Radio_adblock
    RadioGroup rgAdBlock = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_adblock);
    String radioAdBlock = ((RadioButton) findViewById(rgAdBlock.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();

    // constructor method for Input field
    EditText nameTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
    String hasName = nameTextField.getText().toString();

    // Is the button now checked

    radioVirus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            if (checkedId = radio_virusno) {
            //set the style of the things you want to disable here

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how this code answers the question.

Comment: was showing "ivan" my current code. It was not supposed to be a solution. was in a rush. sorry...